# Is there a hello world heap overflow example?

Tags: c, linux, heap-memory

Is there a hello world heap overflow example? Anyone has a demo?

Comment: What's a hello world heap overflow? while(1) malloc(1);

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    const size_t t=1<<24;
    while(1)
        memset(malloc(t), 0xDE, t);
}
```

Kills it pretty sweetly in no time at all!